# Python - Exit Kafka queue once all messages have been read

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to read some data of a Kafka queue using Python as shown in the below code:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import sys
import json 
import pandas as pd


bootstrap_servers = [localhost]
topicName = 'topic'
consumer = KafkaConsumer (topicName, group_id = 'topic',bootstrap_servers = bootstrap_servers, auto_offset_reset = 'earliest')

data_list = []
for message in consumer:
    print(message)
    data = json.loads(message.value)
    df = pd.json_normalize(data)
    data_list.append(df)
```

This seems to be running in a loop forever unless I kill the connection. Is there a way how I can stop/come out of this loop after having read all of the messages or there are no new messages in the queue?

Answer (score 2):

The [poll](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.poll) method should be what you're looking for.

Just be aware of the `max_records` parameters defaulting to `max_poll_records` which is 500 records if not changed

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible to just set: `gotNewMessages=false` flag, then wait one second, and then `if flag == false`, you quit.

(You should change the `gotNewMessages=true` right after the message is received)